# Reading multi line inputs in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read multiple lines of input from the command line in C++ and store them into an array. This is my code.

```
std::string line;
    int in;
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)){
        if(line == "^D") break;
        v.push_back(line);
    }
    for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;

    }
```

The stdin goes into an infinite loop and I can't seem to figure out how to prevent that. Basically the behavior targeted is that two consecutive press of enter without any input should terminate the stdin loop and run the program.

Comment: `"^D"` isn't a thing, you probably meant to check for `cin.eof()` which is triggered by pressing CTRL-D. But that's OS specific.

Comment: Typing `Ctrl-D` (in linux) should cause the loop to end, no need to test for it explicitly (if that's what you are doing).

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve. I want the stdin to terminate and the program to run on two successive presses of enter

Comment: IF there's no more input line the program should run is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 10):

I would test to see if the string is empty.  If so, break.  Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> v;

while(std::getline(std::cin, line)){
    if (line.empty()){
        break;
    }
    v.push_back(line);
}

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution to the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the loop to stop with two Enter's, you can change the conditional to

```
if(line == "" && v.size() >= 1 && v.back() == "") break;
```

Which should check if the current keystroke and the previous one were Enter's. The `v.size() >= 1` is just to check whether v has any elements in it, and to stop a Segfault if it doesn't have any other elements.

Do note that the last element in the array will be an empty string, and if you want to get rid of that, just write

```
v.pop_back();
```

outside of the first loop, which gets rid of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

the while loop could look like this, with use of .empty() only:

```
while(std::getline(cin, line)){
    if(line.empty() && !v.empty() && v.back().empty()) {
        v.pop_back(); // remove the last empty line
        break;
    }
    v.push_back(line); 
}
```